# MapReduce program in Hadoop that implements a simple “People You Might Know”

Tags: java, hadoop

The ​input ​file ​contains ​the ​adjacency ​list ​and ​has ​multiple ​lines ​in ​the ​following ​format:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Friends 
{

public class FriendsMap extends Mapper < LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable >
    {
    private Text friendsAB;
    private Text friendsBA;
    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private IntWritable oneLess = new IntWritable(-999999999);
        //@SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override 
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 
            String friendsOfA[] = null;     //This will be all of the friends of the user in this row
            String oneRow[] = value.toString().split("\t,");    //Break the row up into users IDs
            String userA = oneRow[0];       //This is the main user for this row
            for (int i=1; i < oneRow.length; i++)   //Create an array of the rest of the users in this row
            {
                friendsOfA[i-1] = oneRow[i];
            }
            for (int i=0; i < oneRow.length; i++)   //Output the main user in pairs with all friends plus a lagre negative #
            {
                friendsAB.set(userA + " " + friendsOfA[i]);
                context.write(friendsAB, oneLess);
                System.out.println(friendsAB + " " + oneLess);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < friendsOfA.length; i++)     //Output each friend pair plus the number 1
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < friendsOfA.length; j++) 
                {
                    friendsAB.set(friendsOfA[i] + " " + friendsOfA[j]);
                    friendsBA.set(friendsOfA[j] + " " + friendsOfA[i]);
                    context.write(friendsAB, one);
                    context.write(friendsBA, one);
                    System.out.println(friendsAB + " " + one);
                    System.out.println(friendsBA + " " + one);
                }
            }
        }
    }

class FriendReducer extends Reducer < Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
    { 
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable(); 
        @Override 
        public void reduce( Text key, Iterable < IntWritable > values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 
            int sum = 0; 
            for (IntWritable val : values) 
            { 
                sum += val.get(); 
            } 
            if (sum > 1)
            {
                result.set( sum); 
                context.write( key, result);
            }
            //At this point I have all pairs of users with recomenede friends and a count of how many times they each
            //friend has been recomended to a user.
            //I need to sort by user and then by number of recomendations.
            //Then print the user <tab> all recomendations with commas between them.
        } 
    }


public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
    { 
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance( conf, "Friends");
        job.setJarByClass(Friends.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath( job, new Path("input")); 
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath( job, new Path("output")); 
        job.setMapperClass( FriendsMap.class); 
        job.setCombinerClass( FriendReducer.class); 
        job.setReducerClass( FriendReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass( Text.class); 
        job.setOutputValueClass( IntWritable.class);

        System.exit( job.waitForCompletion( true) ? 0 : 1); 
    }
}
```

This is the errors I am getting in the console.

> 17/11/15 16:05:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable 17/11/15 16:06:54 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id 17/11/15
>   16:06:54 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with
>   processName=JobTracker, sessionId= 17/11/15 16:06:54 WARN
>   mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments.
>   Applications should implement Tool for the same. 17/11/15 16:06:55
>   WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be
>   found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String). 17/11/15 16:06:55
>   INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2 17/11/15
>   16:07:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local426825952_0001
>   17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in
>   config null 17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   OutputCommitter is
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter 17/11/15
>   16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks 17/11/15
>   16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local426825952_0001_m_000000_0 17/11/15 16:07:05 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code
>   0 17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin
>   : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@670217f0
>   17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local426825952_0001_m_000001_0 17/11/15 16:07:05 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/15 16:07:05 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin :
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1688e9ff 17/11/15
>   16:07:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
>   17/11/15 16:07:05 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local426825952_0001
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Friends$FriendsMap.()  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Friends$FriendsMap.()  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Friends$FriendsMap.()  at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
>     ... 8 more 17/11/15 16:07:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
>   17/11/15 16:07:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete:
>   job_local426825952_0001 17/11/15 16:07:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Counters: 0

After changing the classes to Static this is the new errors.

> 17/11/16 04:28:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable 17/11/16 04:28:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id 17/11/16
>   04:28:52 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with
>   processName=JobTracker, sessionId= 17/11/16 04:28:52 WARN
>   mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments.
>   Applications should implement Tool for the same. 17/11/16 04:28:52
>   WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be
>   found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String). 17/11/16 04:28:53
>   INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2 17/11/16
>   04:28:54 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config
>   null 17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job:
>   job_local1593958162_0001 17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   OutputCommitter is
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter 17/11/16
>   04:28:54 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks 17/11/16
>   04:28:54 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local1593958162_0001_m_000000_0 17/11/16 04:28:54 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code
>   0 17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin
>   : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@57d51956
>   17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split:
>   file:/home/cloudera/workspace/Assignment4/input/Sample4.txt:0+4106187
>   17/11/16 04:28:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class =
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer 17/11/16 04:28:54
>   INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local1593958162_0001_m_000001_0 17/11/16 04:28:55 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin :
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@774140b3 17/11/16
>   04:28:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split:
>   file:/home/cloudera/workspace/Assignment4/input/Sample4.txt~:0+0
>   17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class =
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer 17/11/16 04:28:55
>   INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner:  17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.MapTask:
>   Starting flush of map output 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.Task:
>   Task:attempt_local1593958162_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the
>   process of commiting 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
>   17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO mapred.Task: Task
>   'attempt_local1593958162_0001_m_000001_0' done. 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task:
>   attempt_local1593958162_0001_m_000001_0 17/11/16 04:28:55 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete. 17/11/16 04:28:55
>   WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1593958162_0001
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Friends$FriendsMap.map(Friends.java:36)   at
>   Friends$FriendsMap.map(Friends.java:1)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local1593958162_0001 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 16 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=4674 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes
>   written=139416 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE:
>   Number of read operations=0 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE: Number of large read operations=0 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=125 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0 17/11/16
>   04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
>   17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes)
>   snapshot=0 17/11/16 04:28:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total
>   committed heap usage (bytes)=363696128

I think this is the part that is the most troublesome.

[Screen Shot of some errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Z9l.jpg)

This is the updated code.

```
public static class FriendsMap extends Mapper < LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable >
    {
        //@SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override 
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 

            String friendsOfA[];    //This will be all of the friends of the user in this row
            friendsOfA = new String[] {};
            String friendsAB        = "1";      //This will be used to create pairs of users
            String friendsBA        = "2";      //This will be used to create pairs of users
            Text pairA;
            Text pairB; 
            IntWritable one     = new IntWritable(1);           //1 if they are not an existing pair here
            IntWritable oneLess = new IntWritable(-999999999);  // if they are an existing pair

            String oneRow[] = value.toString().split("\t,");    //Break the row up into users IDs
            Text userA = new Text(oneRow[0]);                                   //This is the main user for this row
            for (int i=1; i < oneRow.length; i++)   //Create an array of the rest of the users in this row
            {
                friendsOfA[i-1] = oneRow[i];
            }
            for (int i=0; i < oneRow.length; i++)   //Output the main user in pairs with all friends plus a large negative #
            {                                       //We do not want to recommend them as friends because they are friends 
                Text FOA = new Text (friendsOfA[i]);
                friendsAB = (userA + " " + FOA);
                Text pair = new Text (friendsAB);
                context.write(pair, oneLess);
                System.out.println(pair + " " + oneLess);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < friendsOfA.length; i++)     //Output each friend pair plus the number 1
            {                                               //We want to recommend them as potential friends
                for (int j = i + 1; j < friendsOfA.length; j++) 
                {
                    Text FOA = new Text (friendsOfA[i]);
                    Text FOB = new Text (friendsOfA[j]);
                    friendsAB = (FOA + " " + FOB);
                    friendsBA = (FOB + " " + FOA);
                    pairA = new Text (friendsAB);
                    pairB = new Text (friendsBA);
                    context.write(pairA, one);
                    context.write(pairB, one);
                    System.out.println(pairA + " " + one);
                    System.out.println(pairB + " " + one);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the new set of errors.

> 17/11/16 11:59:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable 17/11/16 11:59:27 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id 17/11/16
>   11:59:27 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with
>   processName=JobTracker, sessionId= 17/11/16 11:59:27 WARN
>   mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments.
>   Applications should implement Tool for the same. 17/11/16 11:59:27
>   WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be
>   found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String). 17/11/16 11:59:27
>   INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2 17/11/16
>   11:59:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1899187381_0001
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in
>   config null 17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
>   OutputCommitter is
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter 17/11/16
>   11:59:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks 17/11/16
>   11:59:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local1899187381_0001_m_000000_0 17/11/16 11:59:29 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code
>   0 17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin
>   : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@4f94aaa1
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split:
>   file:/home/cloudera/workspace/Assignment4/input/Sample4.txt:0+4106187
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class =
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer 17/11/16 11:59:29
>   INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100 17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720 17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680 17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task:
>   attempt_local1899187381_0001_m_000001_0 17/11/16 11:59:29 WARN
>   mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is
>   deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin :
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@622ecc38 17/11/16
>   11:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split:
>   file:/home/cloudera/workspace/Assignment4/input/Sample4.txt~:0+0
>   17/11/16 11:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class =
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer 17/11/16 11:59:29
>   INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner:  17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO mapred.MapTask:
>   Starting flush of map output 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO mapred.Task:
>   Task:attempt_local1899187381_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the
>   process of commiting 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
>   17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task
>   'attempt_local1899187381_0001_m_000001_0' done. 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task:
>   attempt_local1899187381_0001_m_000001_0 17/11/16 11:59:30 INFO
>   mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete. 17/11/16 11:59:30
>   WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1899187381_0001
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0    at
>   Friends$FriendsMap.map(Friends.java:41)   at
>   Friends$FriendsMap.map(Friends.java:1)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local1899187381_0001 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 16 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=4674 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes
>   written=139416 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE:
>   Number of read operations=0 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE: Number of large read operations=0 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=125 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0 17/11/16
>   11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
>   17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes)
>   snapshot=0 17/11/16 11:59:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total
>   committed heap usage (bytes)=363618304

Comment: can you share the sample data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've delcared the classes as inner classes, which might be causing issues. An inner class can only exist within an instance of the [enclosing class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Its probably easier to change them to static classes.

```
public class Friends {

    public static class FriendsMap extends Mapper <...> {}

    public static class FriendReducer extends Reducer <...> {}

    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Friends");
        job.setJarByClass(Friends.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("input")); 
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("output")); 
        job.setMapperClass(FriendsMap.class); 
        job.setCombinerClass(FriendReducer.class); 
        job.setReducerClass(FriendReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); 
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit( job.waitForCompletion( true) ? 0 : 1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I made the changes you suggested, however I still have the many of the same errors.  I think you are on the right track.

Comment: You now have code errors, which should be added as new questions in my view. Your job is now running which this question asked about.

Comment: Your errors now are just null pointers. Look for objects you arent creating, but trying to use such as `friendsAB` and `friendsBA`.

Comment: Thank you Binary Nerd.  You were correct, once I learned how to fix a null pointer it started working.